# How do I convert a .gif, .jpg or .jpeg to a .png using PHP?

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I've been looking for a way to convert an image based on the formats quoted in the title yesterday but nothing worked for me.

I tried with this :

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif('test.gif');
imagepng($image, 'image.png', 70);
imagedestroy($image);


$img1 = new Image("test.gif");
$img2 = new Image("image.png");
$img2->merge($img1, 9, 9);
$img2->save("merged.png",IMAGETYPE_PNG);
```

As you can see, the first block creates a new empty .png and the second tries to merge the image I wanna convert with the new empty one, it's kind of a cheating way but it's the only one that gives me results. I'm open to any kind of help, so if you could help me, it would be really cool from you guys.

Btw, the rest of the code is an upload script that works perfectly. I can show it to you if it's necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage try this but it consumes more RAM

Comment: → `imagecreatefromPNG` ←, → `'...gif'` ← Yeah, not surprised it doesn't work…

Comment: Yep, my bad, it was just a test I did just before I posted, lmao

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename)), "MyImg.png");`